# Error save product with extra fields {"step1":["This form should not contain extra fields."]} prestashop 1.7.5

Tags: prestashop

I am trying to add a YouTube video in the product carousel, I cannot save the video URL in the database, I understand that creating the column in the `ps_product` and `ps_product_shop` tables is saved by adding the correct name to the input, I attach screenshots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

override class product

[image]

Comment: You have overriden Product, have you deleted class_index.php ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please do not post code as picture. Please try to use StackOverflow's code formatting tools.